# Why I can't get source code an documentation by using maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, rxtx

I'm got RXTX library in Java Maven project in Eclipse by adding dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.rxtx</groupId>
    <artifactId>rxtx</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

But how to ask maven to download documentation and source code for it?

I have settings in project properties that should help me with that, but I don't see any documents and sources.

[image]

I have plugin that I hope will help me to download source code:

```
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

But after execution `mvn verify` I found that source and doc are not available:

```
m2e-lastUpdated.properties
11/07/2018  07:03 PM                 0 rxtx-2.1.7-javadoc.jar-not-available
11/07/2018  07:03 PM               255 rxtx-2.1.7-javadoc.jar.lastUpdated
11/07/2018  07:03 PM                 0 rxtx-2.1.7-sources.jar-not-available
11/07/2018  07:03 PM               255 rxtx-2.1.7-sources.jar.lastUpdated
11/05/2018  12:33 PM            59,464 rxtx-2.1.7.jar
11/05/2018  12:33 PM               126 rxtx-2.1.7.jar.sha1
11/05/2018  12:33 PM               841 rxtx-2.1.7.pom
11/05/2018  12:33 PM               126 rxtx-2.1.7.pom.sha1
11/05/2018  12:33 PM               192 _remote.repositories
```

What else I can do to get RXTX library source code?

Comment: The version and/or library is a little bit old...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, it seems [the Maven repository](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/rxtx/rxtx/2.1.7/) doesn't contain the source code for RXTX.

You can find [the source code for RXTX on GitHub](https://github.com/rxtx/).